# TempData Return Null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I initialize Tempdata in action
i need to retrieve tempdata in another action but it return null.

```
    public  IActionResult GetRestaurants(int? id)
    {
        TempData["HotelID"] = id;

        return Ok();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddRestaurant()
    {

      int x =int.Parse(TempData["HotelID"].ToString());

    }
```

Comment: You didn't even post the code for `OK()`...

Comment: I try it and still return null

Comment: Is your project directly created in version 3.0 or migrated from 2.x to 3.0? I tested it against your code with the version 3.0, but I got the value of tempdata.Could you share a demo that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: The project directly created in version 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ConfigureServices method of startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }
```

**Configure method of startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
        }
```

more detail can be found at [Session and app state in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

**Index1 Action method**

```
 public IActionResult Index()
            {
                Message = $"Customer abcd added";
                TempData["name"] = "Test data";
                TempData["age"] = 30;
                TempData.Keep();


               // Session["name"] = "Test Data";

                return View();
            }
```

**index2 action method**

```
 public IActionResult About()
        {

           var userName = TempData.Peek("name").ToString();


           var userAge = int.Parse(TempData.Peek("age").ToString());
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: can you put your startup.cs ?

Comment: public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            });
            services.AddAutoMapper();
            services.AddDbContext<ConnectHotelWSSteigenBergerContext>(options =>
                                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

        }

Comment: public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();}
else{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseSession();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
}

Comment: What is the version of asp.net core  you are using?

Comment: If it is 2.x range then you need to set comparability version `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.your version)`

Comment: I used .net core 3

Comment: Can you try to set compatibility and check?

Comment: In microsoft  official documentation they have mention to set compatablity.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I write 
SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
and 3 and leatest and also return null